# getInitialProps causing ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error on my live site, but not on my local version

Tags: reactjs, redirect, cookies, next.js

So, I've been trying to implement cookies on my website, to keep track of a list of JavaScript objects, so the page stays consistent when the user comes back to it. I've been following this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-cookies-to-persist-state-in-nextjs-934bed5e6da5).

On my local machine, using `npm run dev` on localhost:3000, it works absolutely perfect. However, when I push the commit to GitHub, it builds on Vercel without any issue, but when I try and access the live website on the internet, it gives me a 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error.

I'm pretty confused as to why it would work perfectly fine on my locally hosted site, but freaks out and does not work when it's put into production.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to `getInitialProps` because when I comment out the implementation in my `index.js` file, it still doesn't work, but when I comment out `getInitialProps`, it works again.

Here is the code I think may be the problem.

```
Home.getInitialProps = async ({req, res}) => {

    const data = parseCookies(req)
  
    if (res) {
     if (Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object) {
       res.writeHead(301, { Location: "/" })
       res.end()
     }
   }
   
   return {
     data: data && data,
   }

}
```

And here is the code for that `parseCookies` method, which is imported as

```
import { parseCookies } from "../helpers/index"
```

within my `index.js`

```
import cookie from "cookie"
export function parseCookies(req) {
  return cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || "" : document.cookie)
}
```

I'm super confused at this point, I've walked myself through the code a dozen times now and still have no idea what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated! And please lemme know if there's anymore info I can provide!

Comment: Is the Home page component handling the `/` path? If so, then you'll get an infinite redirect if there aren't cookies set. If you delete the cookies you have locally, you should be able to replicate the issue then.

Comment: @juliomalves ah, i see, you are absolutely right. Doesen't the home page have to handle '/' though? Can you help point me in the right direction to fix this? And could you help me understand why this is happening? Why do no cookies force an infinite redirect?

Comment: The homepage can handle `/`, that's completely fine. The redirect happens because `Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object` returns true when no cookies are set. When this happens you redirect to `/` (the homepage) which then makes the check again and redirects again, and so on. Tell me, what was the idea behind having the redirect? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @juliomalves so, i'll be completely honest with you, i was really just following that tutorial i linked for you above. I believe the reason we were doing that was to check if there are cookies and if they’re still valid. We do this check using the `res` object. If the `data` object is empty, it means the cookie isn’t valid. If the cookie isn’t valid, we then redirect the user back to the index page rather than showing a flash of the HomePage before redirecting the user.

Comment: Right, so the redirect logic should probably live in the other pages, but not in the homepage, since that's the redirect destination.

Comment: @juliomalves Ah, i see now. I removed that code and it works now! Thanks man! If ya put that as the answer ill mark it as much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error occurs because `Object.keys(data).length === 0 && data.constructor === Object` returns `true` when no cookies are set and you access the homepage. When this happens the redirect takes you back to `/` (the homepage) which then makes the check again and a new redirect occurs, and so on.

Locally, you probably have cookies set, so you don't experience the issue. However, when you access the website hosted on Vercel, no cookies are present initially, which triggers the infinite redirect cycle.

To fix the issue simply remove the logic from the homepage, since that's the redirect destination. You can still have it on other pages and redirect to the homepage, though.